# Git ignoring files using global ignore file not working

Tags: git, gitignore

I created file .gitignore_global in my home directory and then run the command:

```
git config --global core.excludefiles ~/.gitignore_global
```

Then I added pattern ***.tmp** in file ~/.gitignore_global to exclude file with .tmp extension but file is not excluded as:

[image]

But, adding pattern locally i.e local ignore is working.

What is wrong here?

Comment: This should help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Comment: Which one answer in the link? is it answer at the top?

Comment: Ignore does not affect files which you have already added or committed.

Comment: files were added after the git config ignore was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config option is `core.excludesfile`, not `core.excludefiles`.